# encrypting/ decrypting strings to text

Tags: ios, security, encryption

I am creating an app that would allow people to share sensitive info with each other via the iphone sms app. I want to make use of the security framework that apple provides, using keys that the people sharing that data know before hand to encrypt and decrypt strings. I don't have much knowledge about the whole keychain system on iOS devices or security protocols in general so does anyone know any good resources for learning about this stuff?

Comment: How will you share keys? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try

- http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/3/29/simple-iphone-keychain-access.html
- http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code
- http://dev-metal.blogspot.com/2010/08/howto-use-keychain-in-iphone-sdk-to.html